# Targeting class on a javascript character counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a character counter using javascript and a rich text editor on a form on our site. The count works on standard textareas but because of the rich text editor the textarea is display none and the rich text editor becomes a div with a class assigned.  How can we change the code below to target the new div class: .nicEdit-main

Here is our code so far.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var limitnum = 200; // set your int limit for max number of characters

    function limiting(obj, limit) {
        var cnt = $("#counter > span");
        var txt = $(obj).val(); 
        var len = txt.length;

        // check if the current length is over the limit
        if(len > limit){
            $(obj).val(txt.substr(0,limit));
            $(cnt).html(len-1);
        }
        else { 
            $(cnt).html(len);
        }

        // check if user has less than 20 chars left
        if(limit-len <= 20) {
            $(cnt).addClass("warning");
        }
    }

    $('.nicEdit-main').keyup(function(){
        limiting($(this), limitnum);
    });
});
```

The above is supposed to update counter from:

```
 <p id="counter"><span>0</span> characters</p>
```

and take the count from:

```
<div class="nicEdit-main" contenteditable="true" style="width: 846px; margin: 4px; min-height: 131px; overflow: hidden;">Our typed text here...</div>
```

Comment: Maybe try delegating event, e.g inside ready handler: `$(this).on('keyup', '.nicEdit-main', function(){
 limiting($(this), limitnum);
 });`

Comment: Thanks but where exactly should this be in the code?

Comment: Replace `$('.nicEdit-main').keyup(function(){...});` in document ready handler. But this is in case your former keyup event wasn't fired. I'm not sure this is your issue because missing some debug info in your question

Comment: No that didn't do it unfortunately.

Comment: Ya, wasn't the issue. See @Gashaw's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `var txt = $(obj).val();` to `var txt = $(obj).text();` because the div element (obj) doesn't have a value property like textarea (or any other input element).

Comment: Thanks, is it only that line which needs to be changed. I tried it but nothing, still the same...

Comment: Can you provide more details? is there any errors in the console?

Comment: @AlanCarr BUT how do you debug it? Is the keyup event fired or not? You have anyway to provide minimalistic sample in question itself to replicate issue

Comment: Appreciate your help. I've set up a fiddle, please see http://jsfiddle.net/sjam81/k3kyjkx3/

Comment: @AlanCarr But you need to include jQuery in jsFiddle, then it works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/k3kyjkx3/1/

Comment: I havent added it on the fiddle. But on our site we are running: ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js

Comment: @AlanCarr you should also replace `window.onload = function(){ $(document).ready(function(){ YOUR CODE  }) }` with just `$(function(){ YOUR CODE })` (provided that jQuery is loaded).

Comment: @AlanCarr So *maybe* you have to delegate event: http://jsfiddle.net/k3kyjkx3/2/  BUT because you don't give any info regarding your issue and even not answering any question then we can just guessing...

Comment: Sorry I didnt see your extra comments, thats perfect its working. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to Gashaw's answer above.

Change:

```
var txt = $(obj).val();
```

to:

```
var txt = $(obj).text() + $(obj).val();
```

Then it will work for textareas and your div

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't work. To be clear the textarea is hidden with display:none and the div .nicEdit-main is the rich text editor where we are taking the count from. Not sure why its not working...

Comment: Hmm, i've just created a simple page using your markup and javascript above and it behaves nicely.  Try putting a breakpoint in your browsers developer tools and see what $(obj) is.  It may give you a clue?